# How shall I store and check for custom access tokens using MySQL and PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, access-token, database-performance

**Tools:** PHP and MySQL

**Goal:** select a given access token ***quickly*** from MySQL.
Access Token: a long string that is generated by me to be used as part of a session for that user. (generation method is irrelevant in this question) (I do not specify "how long that string is" here as maybe it changes the answer. But, I wish I could use up to 128 chars length for example.

**Question:** Using a long-length varchar as primary key is an O.K. idea for querying access tokens like this before any other action is done? Or, should I expose some integer id too to query with/before access_token comparison/check?

**To summarize:** Would you use a varchar primary key directly for checking a lengthy access_token?

Comment: To achieve good performance, you merely need the column to be indexed.  Whether to further make it your primary key is an incarnation of the [natural vs synthetic](https://www.google.com/search?q=natural+vs+synthetic+OR+surrogate+keys) debate, the answer to which depends on factors not covered in your question.

Comment: @eggyal would it be safe to add an Auto Increment field into access_token table and use it along with the token itself? For example, user will get `"token_id=4, token_str=a45fe............"` So, when comparing it, `Select token_str_from_db FROM access_token WHERE id=4` and compare token_str_from_db with incoming token_str. The only problem I can think of is exposing the number of generated access_tokens. Is that a security flaw? What do you think?

Comment: @frankish - Don't complicate your schema until there is a need.  You have not presented a viable 'need' yet.